# Importing json data into postgres using kafka jdbc sink connector

Tags: java, postgresql, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I'm new to kafka.
My requirement is to load json data from kafka topic to postgres table.

Below is the table structure

```
CREATE TABLE dup_emp (
    emp_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    emp_name text,
    emp_salary integer 
);
```

Was producing messages in json format on to topic manually (i.e., from producer console).
Example, `{"emp_id":1,"emp_name":"bheem","emp_salary":2000}`

And my connector configuration as follows:-

```
curl -X PUT http://localhost:8083/connectors/load_test/config \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{
 "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
 "connection.url":"jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/somedb",
 "connection.user":"user",
 "connection.password":"passwd",
 "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
 "value.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
 "key.converter.schemas.enable":"false",
 "value.converter.schemas.enable":"false",
 "tasks.max" : "1",
 "topics":"dup_emp",
 "table.name.format":"dup_emp",
 "insert.mode":"insert",
 "quote.sql.identifiers":"never"
}'
```

And was ending up with the following error:-

**Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Sink connector 'load_test' is configured with 'delete.enabled=false' and 'pk.mode=none' and therefore requires records with a non-null Struct value and non-null Struct schema, but found record at (topic='dup_emp',partition=0,offset=0,timestamp=1633066307312) with a HashMap value and null value schema.**

As per my knowledge, when we use source connector, it will store schema in schema registry and used by  sink connector for validation. But, now as i'm not using source connector, as I was producing data in json format manually, how can I load data into postgres.

Can someone, help me out in understanding the error in better way and suggest me a proper configuration to load data into postgres.

Comment: Basically, JDBC sink works the best with a schema. Error says that you need schemas.enable=true which means your "manual" json messages need a schema within them... Or you can switch to using Avro with the registry and produce the same json records with `kafka-avro-console-producer`. You can also try adjusting pk.mode config

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer I appreciate your help. Can you please provide any useful resources related to , how I can achieve this with avro with registry.

Comment: You can search the Confluent blog or Robin Moffitt's blog/YouTube. Or you can try something on your own, based on resources you've found, then create new posts for any new errors you run into