# Loading data in plain json format to postgresql using kafka jdbc sink connector

Tags: json, postgresql, apache-kafka

Here is my earlier question :- [importing-json-data-into-postgres-using-kafka-jdbc-sink-connector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69401642/importing-json-data-into-postgres-using-kafka-jdbc-sink-connector)

I was able to load json data when I produce data in schema and payload format. But, for me it is not possible to have schema assigned to every record. So, I started to look for other solution and found [Schema Inferencing for JsonConverter](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-301%3A+Schema+Inferencing+for+JsonConverter). As per the documentation I disabled the **value.converter.schemas.enable**  and enabled **value.converter.schemas.infer.enable** but still ,I'm facing the same error

i.e.,
**Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Sink connector 'load_test' is configured with 'delete.enabled=false' and 'pk.mode=none' and therefore requires records with a non-null Struct value and non-null Struct schema, but found record at (topic='dup_emp',partition=0,offset=0,timestamp=1633066307312) with a HashMap value and null value schema.**

my configuartion:-

```
curl -X PUT http://localhost:8083/connectors/load_test/config \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{
 "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
 "connection.url":"jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/somedb",
 "connection.user":"user",
 "connection.password":"passwd",
 "value.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
 "value.converter.schemas.enable":"false",
 "value.converter.schemas.infer.enable": "true",
 "tasks.max" : "1",
 "topics":"dup_emp",
 "table.name.format":"dup_emp",
 "insert.mode":"insert",
 "quote.sql.identifiers":"never"
}'
```

I have gone through the [sink_config_options](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-jdbc/current/sink-connector/sink_config_options.html) Here as per my understanding, I need to generate record with key where key contains a struct of primary key fields and need to set **pk_mode:record_key** and **delete.enabled:true**

Correct me if I understood wrongly. If my understanding is correct, how do we produce records with key of type struct (which contains all primary keys) and Finally, how do I make it successfully populate data in postgres from topic.

Answer (score 1):

> it is not possible to have schema assigned to every record

Then it's not possible to use this connector, as it requires a schema in order to know what fields and types exist.

The KIP you linked to is "under discussion", with an unassigned, open JIRA, not implemented.

The alternative is to not use JSON, but a structured binary format such as the ones Confluent provides (Avro or Protobuf). You can [use KSQL before consuming in Connect to do this translation](https://gist.github.com/rmoff/165b05e4554c41719b71f1a47ee7b113) (requires running Confluent Schema Registry)

Otherwise, you need to write your own Converter (or Transform) and add it to the Connect classpath such that it returns a Struct